# SQL Server development environment for a small team - best practice needed

Tags: sql-server, development-environment

We are a small team of 5 working on a same database. It's a reporting solution so there is about 5 more 3rd party databases which is source of data.

It is very important to have latest data for development, so sometimes those linked databases backed up and restored on each dev's local SQL Server(an they pretty big). Then there is always a problem with dev's databases being out of sync from each other. When it was 2 of us, there was no problem. But when more people got added to the team - it starts to be a pain to arrange.

So, I was thinking about building a dev SQL Server. It will be more powerful then laptops (faster queries) and latency should not be an issue. We always have internet when working and that is not a problem either. I only wonder if it's OK to work together out of the same database. Sounds like a good plan, but not sure if there will be any "gotchas" comparing having databases locally. We will be able to keep data fresh for everyone easy. And I think it should save time and making easier to build/rebuild dev machines if needed. I even think that database where we code can be 1 per person, but still on a same box. This way we can always compare them "right on a box" if needed.

Any advices on this setup? Pro's or Con's?

Comment: This will probably get closed as too broad / opinion based, but for what it worth it's more or less "standard" nowaday to have a dev database per developer. You also need set up scripts with good test data. You track your database changes not as a state but as a set of transitions and make sure that every transition is applied to a particular copy of the database.

Comment: Why is it so important they have current production data to develop against?  The structure is all the matters for development.  Access to current production data on a central server would usually only be needed to help answer questions about data patterns, potentially dirty data, or to help verify assumptions about business rules or use cases.

Comment: Not current, but recent. Weekly will be good. Structure is pretty simple, but data itself changes. Just like you said, patterns change, how they use system changes and data changes and it is useful to have this for development.

Comment: Having the database in version control is usually also a good idea, so that you can manage all the changes that have been done easily and if you end up having separate instances for each developer then it's easy to apply changes made by the other developers.

Answer (score 0):

A new option is to use isolated containers on a shared server, with clones of the production database environment.   Full disclosure, I work for Windocks, where this is the primary use of SQL Server containers.   The most recent release includes built-in SQL Server db cloning.   Benefits of this approach include speed (environments deliverd in <1 minute), and license and labor savings by going to a shared server rather than a score of VMs.